# Multiple UPDATE in single transaction vs one UPDATE with big WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

what is more efficient:

```
START TRANSACTION
UPDATE mytable SET foo = 'bar' WHERE (col1 = 813242) AND (col2 = 25343);
UPDATE mytable SET foo = 'bar' WHERE (col1 = 312643) AND (col2 = 8353);
UPDATE mytable SET foo = 'bar' WHERE (col1 = 843564) AND (col2 = 41233);
UPDATE mytable SET foo = 'bar' WHERE (col1 = 321312) AND (col2 = 5325);
UPDATE mytable SET foo = 'bar' WHERE (col1 = 554235) AND (col2 = 6321);
... x 10,000 times or more
COMMIT;
```

or

```
UPDATE mytable SET foo = 'bar' WHERE
((col1 = 16344) AND (col2 = 5456)) OR
((col1 = 42134) AND (col2 = 5436)) OR
((col1 = 84563) AND (col2 = 2321)) OR
((col1 = 43216) AND (col2 = 4267)) OR
((col1 = 53248) AND (col2 = 6234)) OR
... x 10,000 times or more
```

Assuming I have `UNIQUE` index on (col1,col2)

So my guess is 1st option is nice because of index but it's split into multiple queries, 2nd option is nice because it's only one query but on another hand it does full table scan

this is `EXPLAIN` when not using `OR`:

> type: ref, possible_keys: myindex_UNIQUE,  key: myindex_UNIQUE, ref: const

this is `EXPLAIN` when using `OR`:

> type: ALL, possible_keys: myindex_UNIQUE, key: null, ref: null

and is there any limit for query `WHERE` clause?

I aim for max speed

Comment: So the pattern is `col1 = N AND col2 = N+1` (that is, `col2 = col1 + 1`? This may be possible and maybe a lot more efficient with a join...

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski there is no pattern, this is just an example

Comment: Peter, do you repeat 10000 times the UPDATE statement or the block from START to COMMIT ?

Comment: @Paul: UPDATE statement, I edited my question

Comment: @GolezTrol: It is not so simple. The effect of one statement could be easily cancelled by huge memory consumption and high swap file usage.

Comment: @Peter: I know that this is not the straight answer, but I would suggest you to use no-transaction solution, with separate UPDATE statements if this is acceptable and if a number of records to be updated per single query is few. Long transactions aren't good things.

Comment: A switch to noSQL is not one to take lightly, and I'm surprised that this advice has been given twice now without a proper use case being specified. Updating 10.000 records isn't *that* bad if it has to be done only now and then (a couple of times per day shouldn't be an issue), and it's hardly a reason to think about a different database at all.

Comment: How do you get the list of the value pairs? Do you have a (select) query to retrieve the list of the rows to update? If you use a select statement to retrieve them, could you use that statement in the update?

Comment: @Pred external source (API).

Comment: Hmmm.. A possible solution could be to insert the result of the API call into a temporary/helper table (possibly with indexes) and use that table as the filter of the update query. This could help if your table contains much more rows than the count of the rows to update. You can truncate or drop the temporary/helper table after the update. The temp table could use a memory based storage engine to maximize the performance.

Comment: @Pred: actually this is very good idea and this is what I will do! thanks. add the answer if you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the conversation in the comments, a possible solution:

If you have a large table and a list of values to identify the rows to update, you can create a helper table for the list of values.

Based on the example in the question, the table could be something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable_operation (
    col1 INT
  , col2 INT
) ENGINE = MEMORY;
```

Please note, that the create statement contains the `ENGINE = MEMORY` hint, so the table will be stored in the memory instead of the disk.

Load the values into this table prior the update.

After all values are loaded into the helper table, you can use the following query to update the values in the production table.

```
UPDATE
  mytable
SET
  foo = 'bar'
WHERE
  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytable_operation MO WHERE mytable.col1 = MO.col1 AND mytable.col2 = MO.col2)
```

Of course, you can use any DML statements to manipulate the production data. (UPDATE with joins, `DELETE`, `INSERT..ON DUPLICATE KEY`, etc)

When you finished the data manipulation, you can truncate or drop the helper table.

If the amount of rows are slightly larger in the production table, this solution could be faster than the solutions in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think theoretically the second one will be faster, but it's merely an educated guess.

It's one statement, so it might need less parsing, less initialization, less roundtrips.

The first one might be faster because it uses the index to find the record. But 10.000 index lookups will probably be slower than a full table scan as well, so I think that advantage is gone as well.

One reason multiple statements can be slower, is when you run the separate updates in a loop from a program. In that case, you got 10.000 times the request/response overhead.

As long as you don't do that and just send the update(s) as a single request, I think performance will be similar and any differences will depend on the hardware and configuration of the server, as well as the current load, the amount of data in the table and the number of rows that you update (or will it always be exactly 10.000?). All in all I can't give you an exact answer, but I hope I've given you insight in some of the factors that affect this performance.

Answer (score -2):

use nosql engine for fastest results when inserting/updating

if you want to see how your index is working , replace the update with a SELECT and run it with explain. This should give you an idea if an index is used the way you want

[EXPLAIN how to](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html)

and don't forget that an index will normally slow down any update/insert
it s useful in the where clause only

Comment: An index will slow down an insert, but an update statement usually has a where clause too. Indexes slow down updates if the index is on an updated field instead of a searched field. Basically, indexes slow down DML statements if they cause the index to change.

Comment: switching to noSQL is not an option. I made EXPLAIN queries and as I suspected only 1st option uses index properly